# How to make vertically aligned flash charts horizontal in oracle apex

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

In oracle apex,I want these dials to make horizontal..(please refer attachment)
[image]

what setting should be done?
My current settings are :

[image]

Comment: I don't understand "horizontal". Do you mean you want the charts to be next to eachother instead of under eachother, or is it something about the chart itself? If layout related: mention your apex version specifically, and the theme, browser.

Comment: Hi Tom,  Apex version is 4.2.6.   We want the chart to be next to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you could create 3 html regions as Borderless Regions - Without Title . These will act as parent regions and can be set so they would be next to each other. You would set the 1st region's Grid Layout as:

```
Start New Grid: No
Start New Row: Yes
Column: 1
Column Span: 4
```

The 2nd region would be:

```
Start New Grid: No
Start New Row: No
Column: 5
Column Span: 4
```

The 3rd region would be:

```
Start New Grid: No
Start New Row: No
Column: 9
Column Span: 4
```

You would set each table's parent region with each of the separate regions you just created.

What this does is that it creates a holding area that are aligned next to each other.If you have more tables you would need to set them the column spans and columns differently.

Answer (score 1):

By the looks of the config, I would say it's apex 4.2

If you want them horizontally aligned by the apex engine, you need to include each one of them in regions with at least a "div with id" template (in your example there's no template set), then on the first one set the "Start new grid" parameter to "Yes", and in the rest set "Start new grid" to "No", and "Start new row" to "No", then it will appear another parameter called "Start new column" and this one set it to "Yes".

With no template assigned to the region apex does not wrap it with the "grid" which is a regular table.

Comment: Hi Typo, I have added template - blank region, it is still not working. what do u mean by  "div with id" template? Could you please elaborate.

Comment: @Gayathri The "div with id" template will not be available in all themes - which is why I also asked what theme you are using. That being said, as Typo points out, you should assign some template to the region. This does not have to be a template which adds visual "fluff" to the region, but just one which will cause apex to add the grid settings. The "div with id" region is exactly such one: it just provides a div element for the region element and no additional visual effects, making it ideal for these kind of tricks. It might only be in theme 25 and 26 though.

Comment: @Gayathri if the template "div with id" is not available, try with "borderless región (with no heading)"